# Unable to set kernel.core_pattern in K8s

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl, podsecuritypolicy

I am trying to modify the kernel.core_pattern but I am unable to modify it as it is Read-Only.

I have tried:

```
> echo 'kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t' >> /etc/sysctl.conf

> Reload sysctl: sysctl --system
```

```
Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ... sysctl: setting key "kernel.core_pattern": Read-only file system cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

I am no able to add it to the pod yaml either:

```yaml
spec:
  securityContext:
    sysctls:
    - name: kernel.core_pattern
      value: "/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t"
```

I keep getting this: `SysctlForbidden`

I created a PodSecurityPolicy as well:

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: sysctl-psp
spec:
  privileged: false  # Don't allow privileged pods!
  # The rest fills in some required fields.
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: RunAsAny
  runAsUser:
    rule: RunAsAny
  fsGroup:
    rule: RunAsAny
  allowedUnsafeSysctls:
  - kernel.*
```

Still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried fixing some of the highlighting / syntax but couldn't get it all -- can you paste your actual file contents?  note that you'd need a `privileged: true` container to write to that location and that location is **global** to the box -- you're better to do this in host provisioning and not in a pod

Comment: Did you enable unsafe sysctls in kubelet? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/

Comment: @AnthonySottile: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the post. 
```
spec:
  privileged: true  
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
```
To the PodSecurityPolicy.
Still no luck:
root@cbng-777cc47489-28jqn:/# sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t
sysctl: setting key "kernel.core_pattern": Read-only file syste

Comment: @MariuszK.
Yes. I tried setting sysctl in kubelet as well:
--allowed-unsafe-sysctls=kernel.core_pattern . No Luck.

Comment: Is it enabled on the node? kernel.core_pattern is a node level sysctl and is not supported on kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to edit the kernel.core_pattern on the nodes in the cluster and that was reflected in the pods as well. But is a temporary work around as the core files generated are of zero size.